# Pointers to object properties in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a method that needs to calculate results for two variables in a object, so I am using pointers to return the results. The problem occurs because the object properties are private and can only be accessed through a getter method. The code I have looks like this:

```
Class myObject;
//Some other operations on myObject

double firstPram = myObject.getFirstDouble();
double secondPram = myObject.getSecondDouble();
someFunction(&firstPram, &secondPram);
myObject.setFirstDouble(firstPram);
myObject.setSecondDouble(secondPram);
```

This works but doesn't seem like the most elegant or efficient solution. Doing something like

```
someFunction(&myObject.getFirstDouble(), &myObject.getSecondDouble());
```

doesn't work and I get why. I just want to know if there is a way to access a varible through a method with a pointer.

Comment: does it make sense to make `someFunction` a member function of `Class` ? Or at least to have it called from a member function of `Class` ?

Comment: Why not a simple public function to do all the work?

Comment: Making someFunction a member of the class would cause problems for other parts of the program since it is used in other places too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is "do you really want that an external object edits directly a private variable?". Probably not: you declared it private, so you should edit that through public method in that class. A good way is to pass the entire object to `someFunction` that edit the variables with getter and setter methods.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `someFunction` should be a member of `Class`, because it reads and writes private variable. It can still reuse the standalone `someFunction`. E.g.:

```
void someFunction(double*, double*);

class Class {
    double first_, second_;

public:
    void someFunction() {
        ::someFunction(&first_, &second_);
    }
};
```

Comment: I think doing this would break other parts of my program. I have found another fix for now, but I will take another look at my class structure.

Comment: @Mike159 I don't think it should break existing code because you don't remove anything.

Comment: This code is in another class and the function is used in other places. I'm not saying what you suggested won't work, I just think my class structure needs some changes first.

Answer (score 0):

The second snippet will work if you change function `getFirstDouble` to return reference:

```
double& getFirstDouble()
```

of course it will break encapsulation even more than your current getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

How about having the function `someFunction()` within your class?

Let that function manipulate the object's variables.

So by calling `myObject.someFunction()`, you can do your necessary functionality. Also you don't have to expose the variables by getters and setters too.